Finding connected path in neo4j

I have a graph like the one in the image above with three kinds of nodes and four type of relationships, is there a way I can find all the connected nodes given a (PHN) or (EML) node type value.
Note that give a phone number I want to get to all people connected to this node (directly or indirectly). For example, given (:PHN { val: 100 }) should return both EMP A and EMP B nodes
This is for a contact duplicate/merge suggestion kindof a scenario, if there are any other reference implementations I would like to go through them as well.
Thank you!

To just get the EMP nodes connected to the PHN node with val = 100, add a label expression to the right hand node pattern:
MATCH (:PHN {val: 100})--+(n:EMP)
RETURN DISTINCT n

The DISTINCT returns each EMP node once and allows the query planner to choose a fast plan.
The --+ is a quantified relationship that will match on one or more relationships of any type or direction.

@FinbarGood Is --+ necessary? Wouldn't simply -- work as well?

@cybersam I guess you mean in the case that all the data looks like the screenshot? I took "to get to all people connected to this node (directly or indirectly)" to mean there could be more than one hop required.

Ah, I missed that part. Never mind. :-).

Use a variable-length pattern to find out all reached nodes:
match (a:PHN {value:"x"}) -[*]->(n) return n

This should return all nodes reached from a PHN node containing value="x"

Thanks, this gives me nodes attached directly to the PHN node, how can I get both the EMP nodes from a given PHN node value? Apologies if that wasn't clear from my question, I'll update it.
